# Update of latitude and longitude does not work in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, geocode

I am building an app for renting rooms. I am using active admin and the geocoder gem. Now to my issue: I want to update the address of a room in the active admin panel which works perfectly but it will not update the longitude and latitude columns autoamtically for me... and I have no idea why? How can I make this work?

I have permited the params in **(room.rb - activeadmin)**

```
permit_params :longitude, :latitude
```

I am using also an after_validation in **(room.rb - model)**

```
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
```

Comment: The `latitude` and `longitude` entered in your active_admin form are not being used if the `address` is changed.  What do you have in `address` and is `address` one of the permit_params?

Comment: Yes address was also in the permit params it seems that the issue is only on one record... I recreated the room and it works without any issue still thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why but the issue appears only on one record(room). I have created the room one more time and it works like a charm!